# Showing layout of layout manager from Python console or Python script QGIS 3

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, print-composer, layout-manager

How can I show/open layout '2019_A' of Layout Manager from Python console?

How show window layout specific?

I checked in menu *Interface Customization*, mActionShowLayoutManager and I do not know how to call from Python console.

Answer (score 4):

If you want open a new layout designer dialog for the specified layout.

```
# Open composition
project = QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()
layout = projectLayoutManager.layoutByName("2019_A")
iface.openLayoutDesigner(layout)
```

and for show only manager dialog

```
iface.showLayoutManager ()
```